# OpenCV build with CUDA, TBB, MKL, VTK on Windows

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake-gui

I tried builing OpenCV with Intel TBB, MKL, TBB+MKL, VTK, Qt, Eigen and CUDA enabled. The CMake build worked just fine and generated the Visual Studio solution without an error.

But while building OpenCV on VS 2017, it fails with this.

**opencv_cudev_main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool cv::__termination" (__imp_?__termination@cv@@3_NA) referenced in function DllMain**

**opencv_cudev400.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals**

Here are some more details about the current configuration.

- CMake (v. 3.13.1)
- OpenCV source (v 4.0.0)
- OpenCV Contrib (v 4.0.0)
- Visual Studio 2017(v 15.9.4)
- CUDA Toolkit (v 10.0)
- Intel TBB (v 2019 Update 3)
- Intel MKL (v 2019 Update 3)
- VTK (v 8.1)
- Qt (v. 5.12.0)
- Eigen (v. 3.3.7)
- OS : Windows 10 (build 1809)

Is there something I am overlooking or do I have to change the versions of libraries I am using so they work with Opencv 4.0.0?

Here's my CMake config string

"C:\Libraries\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -B"%openCVRoot%\build" -H"%openCVRoot%\core-src" -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBUILD_opencv_world=ON -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DCUDA_FAST_MATH=ON -DWITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_MKL=ON -DMKL_USE_MULTITHREAD=ON -DMKL_WITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DINSTALL_TESTS=OFF -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_VTK=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_python3=OFF -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="%openCVRoot%\contrib-src\modules" -DWITH_EIGEN=ON

Comment: "it fails" ... you're gonna have to elaborate a bit on that.

Comment: You need to specify each step you performed for building it. Building OpenCV can give headaches. Which steps you performed?

Comment: @DanMašek, updated now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to build from source : https://github.com/opencv/opencv
You need to check whether:

- PATH variables are correctly set, meaning you should have them pointing to the corresponding library. Otherwise, you need to specify the path manually in CMake
- You have the correct versions of the libraries you can check here the list https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html as well as explanations
- if you build libraries by yourself, pay attention that they are in the correct mode (debug/release)
- You should also check you have every library : I don't see Eigen in your list
- Check your version of cmake (version >=3.9.1)

**EDIT**
Since you added the error you had I may have an indication :

Similar issue :
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13208

Initial post about same issue :
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12865

Post about the solution :
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/13209

The patch #13209 should have resolved your issue.

- Try deleting OpenCV and downloading a fresh repository, up to date
- Check that your drivers are updated (for your graphic card)
- Consider using pre-built libraries as indicated in the first paragraph here : https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html

Comment: Hi Patafikss, just updated my question with more details. Going to try one more time now. Thanks the tip!